# Using regex to remove JSON quotes

Tags: java, regex

I am being given some JSON from an external process that I can't change, and I need to modify this JSON string for a downstream Java process to work. The JSON string looks like:

```
{"widgets":"blah","is_dog":"1"}
```

But it needs to look like:

```
{"widgets":blah,"is_dog":"1"}
```

I have to remove the quotes around `blah`. In reality, `blah` is a huge JSON object, and so I've simplified it for the sake of this question. So I figured I'd attack the problem by doing two `String#replace` calls, one before `blah`, and one after it:

```
dataString = dataString.replaceAll("{\"widgets\":\"", "{\"widgets\":");
dataString = dataString.replaceAll("\",\"is_dog\":\"1\"}", ",\"is_dog\":\"1\"}");
```

When I run this I get a vague runtime error:

> Illegal repetition

Can any regex maestros spot where I'm going awrye? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{"widgets":blah,"is_dog":"1"}`  is not valid JSON, what are you using to deserialize it ?

Comment: Of course you could always parse the JSON, parse the embedded object, then reassemble and reserialize.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -- You have to read a little carefully -- "blah" is really `{"someJson":"object"}`.

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to not only remove the surrounding quotes but also un-escape all the embedded quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to escape braces. Braces are used for repetition (`(foo){3}` looks for foo three times in a row); hence the error.

Note: in this case it needs to be double escaping: `\\{`.

Comment: Thanks for actually **answering my question** instead of inferring what *you think I should really be doing,* seeing that no one here understands all the niche details of my situation, and on SO you're scorned for providing too much backstory.

Comment: I think sometimes suggesting what people *should* be doing is a decent response. Otherwise everyone will be parsing HTML with regexps (unreliably)

Comment: @TicketMonster, many questions on this site involve regexes being used to parse things, when another way would work better. I think it is fair to suggest other approaches to your problem.  However, sometimes people do go too far in saying that regexes are always "wrong" for certain types of data.  That's not true; it depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

`{` and `}` in regex have special meaning. They are to mention allowed repetition of patterns. So they are to be escaped here.

Use `\\{\"widgets\":\"", "\\{\"widgets\":` instead of `{\"widgets\":\"", "{\"widgets\":`.

Answer (score 1):

I do wonder if you're better off taking the code for [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) and modifying the `toString()` method to make this a more reliable transformation than using regexps. [Here's the source code,](http://json.org/java/org/json/JSONObject.java) and you're looking for invocations of the `quote()` method

Answer (score 1):

Since the input string looks to be valid json, your best bet would be to parse it with an actual parser to a map-like structure. Regexes are not the right tools for this. Serializing this structure to to something not quite json would then be relatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you simply do the following?

1) Decode the first JSON (which is correct with quotes) into `varJSON1`

2) Get the String "blah" in  `varJSON1` into `varJSON2`

3) Then decode the `varJSON2`